# Code-First EF Core double column length

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I'm using EF Core 1.1 and it's doubling the column length at the database.

```
entityBuilder.Property(t => t.Name)
               .HasMaxLength(200)
               .IsRequired();
```

The code above generate the following script

```
Name = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 200, nullable: false)
```

But when I update the database, it generate the following result

[image]

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One char is two bytes in your encoding